# How to Cast Cell Type with External DataSource

Tags: ios, swift, model, datasource

I have the following external DataSource which I use for various tableViews.

I'd like to make this dynamic and be able to cast the `UITableViewCell` in the `CellConfigurator` to various custom cells.  I make an extension for each model below.  But I need to be able to cast to different cell types in the extension.

```
import UIKit

class ProductSearchDataSource<Model>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    typealias CellConfigurator = (Model, UITableViewCell) -> Void

    var models: [Model]

    private let reuseIdentifier: String
    private let cellConfigurator: CellConfigurator

    init(models: [Model], reuseIdentifier: String, cellConfigurator: @escaping CellConfigurator) {
        self.models = models
        self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier
        self.cellConfigurator = cellConfigurator
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let model = models[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cellConfigurator(model, cell)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ProductSearchDataSource where Model == ProductSearchHistory {
    static func make(for productSearch: [ProductSearchHistory], reuseIdentifier: String = "productSearchTableViewCell") -> ProductSearchDataSource {
        return ProductSearchDataSource(models: productSearch, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) { (productSearch, productSearchTableViewCell) in
            productSearchTableViewCell.textLabel?.text = productSearch.searchHistory
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? You want to specify the type passed in as `productSearchTableViewCell`?

Comment: That is correct.  I need to cast productSearchTableViewCell as ProductSearchCell for example.  then when I use another model I need to be able to pass in a different cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce an additional placeholder type for the cell:

```swift
class ProductSearchDataSource<Model, Cell: UITableViewCell>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    typealias CellConfigurator = (Model, Cell) -> Void

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let model = models[indexPath.row]
        // Note: You may want to handle the downcast better...
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        cellConfigurator(model, cell)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ProductSearchDataSource where Model == ProductSearchHistory, Cell == ProductSearchCell {
    static func make(for productSearch: [ProductSearchHistory], reuseIdentifier: String = "productSearchTableViewCell") -> ProductSearchDataSource {
        return ProductSearchDataSource(models: productSearch, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) { (productSearch, productSearchTableViewCell) in
            // `productSearchTableViewCell` will now have a type of `ProductSearchCell `.
            productSearchTableViewCell.textLabel?.text = productSearch.searchHistory
        }
    }
}
```